# How to find all available maze paths?

Tags: java, recursion, maze

I am trying to write a program that is given a maze and tries to find the way out. M is the entrance, E is the exit, 1s are walls, and 0s are pathways. It is supposed to find each path and put P in the path. It is supposed to find all available paths. Right now it finds part of a path.

Here is the code:

```
public class Maze 
{
    private int size;
    private String[][] board;
    private int total; //# of boards
    private int eX;
    private int eY;
    private int mX;
    private int mY;

    public Maze( int size, String[][] board )
    {
        this.size = size;
        this.board = board;
        total = 0;

    }

    private void find( String c )
    {
        int x=0, y=0;
        for( int i = 0; i < size; i++ )
        {
            for( int j = 0; j < size; j++ )
            {
                if( board[i][j].equals(c) )
                {
                    x = i;
                    y = j;
                }
            }
        }
        if( c.equals("M") )
        {
            mX = x;
            mY = y;
        }
        else if( c.equals("E") )
        {
            eX = x;
            eY = y;
        }
    }

    public void findPath(  )
    {
        find( "M" );
        find( "E" );
        findNext( mX, mY );
    }

    public void findNext( int x, int y )
    { 
        String last = board[x][y];
            if( board[x][y].equals("P") ) board[x][y] = "1";
        board[x][y] = "P";

        if( rightAvailability(x,y) )
        {
            findNext(x+1, y);
        }
        else if( leftAvailability(x,y) )
        {
            findNext(x-1, y);
        }
        else if( aboveAvailability(x,y) )
        {
            findNext(x, y+1);
        }
        else if( belowAvailability(x,y) )
        {
            findNext(x, y-1);
        }
        else
        {
            total++;
            printBoard();
        }

        board[x][y]= last;
    }

    public boolean rightAvailability( int x, int y )
    {
        if( x+1 >= size ) return false;
        else if( board[x+1][y].equals("1") ) return false;
        else if( board[x+1][y].equals("P") ) return false;
        else return true;
    }
    public boolean leftAvailability( int x, int y )
    {
        if( x-1 < 0) return false;
        else if( board[x-1][y].equals("1") ) return false;
        else if( board[x-1][y].equals("P") ) return false;
        else return true;
    }
    public boolean aboveAvailability( int x, int y )
    {
        if( y+1 >= size ) return false;
        else if( board[x][y+1].equals("1") ) return false;
        else if( board[x][y+1].equals("P") ) return false;
        else return true;
    }
    public boolean belowAvailability( int x, int y )
    {
        if( y-1 < 0) return false;
        else if( board[x][y-1].equals("1") ) return false;
        else if( board[x][y-1].equals("P") ) return false;
        else return true;
    }

    public void printBoard()
    {
        System.out.println( "The board number " +total+ " is: ");
        for(int i=0; i< size; i++ )
        {
            for(int j=0; j< size; j++ )
            {
                if( (i==mX) && (j==mY) )
                {
                    System.out.print("M");
                }
                else if( (i==eX) && (j==eY) )
                {
                    System.out.print("E");
                }
                else if( board[i][j].equals("1") )
                {
                    System.out.print("1");
                }
                else if( board[i][j].equals("0") )
                {
                    System.out.print("0");
                }
                else
                {
                    System.out.print("P");
                }
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the tester:

```
public class MazeTester 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        int size = 11;
        String[][] board = new String[][]
            {
                {"1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1"},
                {"1","0","0","0","0","0","1","0","0","0","1"},
                {"1","0","1","0","0","0","1","0","1","0","1"},
                {"E","0","1","0","0","0","0","0","1","0","1"},
                {"1","0","1","1","1","1","1","0","1","0","1"},
                {"1","0","1","0","1","0","0","0","1","0","1"},      
                {"1","0","0","0","1","0","1","0","0","0","1"},
                {"1","1","1","1","1","0","1","0","0","0","1"},
                {"1","0","1","M","1","0","1","0","0","0","1"},
                {"1","0","0","0","0","0","1","0","0","0","1"},
                {"1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1"},  
            };


        Maze m = new Maze( size, board );
        m.findPath();
    }
}
```

Here is the current output:

```
The board number 1 is: 
11111111111
1PPPPP1PPP1
1P1PPP1P1P1
EP1PPPPP1P1
101111101P1
10101PPP1P1
10001P1PPP1
11111P1PP01
101M1P1PP01
100PPP1PP01
11111111111
The board number 2 is: 
11111111111
1PPPPP1PPP1
1P1PPP1P1P1
EP100PPP1P1
101111101P1
10101PPP1P1
10001P1PPP1
11111P1PP01
101M1P1PP01
100PPP1PP01
11111111111
The board number 348 is: 
11111111111
1PPPPP10001
1P1PPP10101
EP1PPPPP101
1011111P101
10101PPP101
10001P10001
11111P10001
101M1P10001
100PPP10001
11111111111
```

EDIT: I added if( board[x][y].equals("P") ) board[x][y] = "1"; at the beginning of findIndex. I also fixed the x <= 0 problem. I updated the output to what I am getting now (it is actually print 348 similar boards).

Comment: When you say it needs to find "all possible paths", doesn't this imply the maze will contain cycles? A strict interpretation of "all possible paths" in the presence of cycles may require an infinite number of paths - do you mean all paths that don't visit a node twice?

Comment: Correct- it doenst visit a node twice.

Comment: In leftAvailability, you're still using y-1 instead of x-1.

Comment: I thought I fixed it on here... i know I fixed it in my actual code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I put a partial Guess at the line:

```
else if( belowAvailability(x,y) )
{
        findNext(x, x-1);
}
```

x-1 should be y-1

Another problem you'll find is in the fact that you're using else if blocks. If you encounter a branch, say

```
1E1
101
1P0
1P1
```

You will try to go right first, and then when that fails miserably, it won't try to go up. You can actually see that in the test output,

```
_._._789_._
_..._6_A54_
_____5_B23_
_._M_4_C10_
_..123_DEF_
___________
```

Numbered in Hex for easy reading convenience. It gets into the lower right corner, then gets stuck; having nowhere else to go the board is printed, and the recursion ends with no backtracking into untested squares.

EDIT again. Still looking, but in the left/right availability you have another x/y mismatch, and you probably only want to deny availability when x-1 < 0 (or y-1); as the goal node is at y=0.

With those changes, and having print trigger only when x==eX && y==eY, I'm getting output of solutions. A great many solutions, but solutions.

One more humorous fact for edit count: you have left/right and up/down backwards. The x coordinate is specifying the row of the input you're looking at, and the y coordinate is specifying the column. It's reasonably common to use r/c in cases like this.

Comment: I have tried each as a if, then if( (x==eX) && (y==eY)) for the printBoard() but that doesnt give me any output

Comment: You wouldn't expect the if(x==eX && y==eY) to give any output because it never actually makes it to the end point.

Comment: I am getting 348 solutions now. I did notice the x/y coordinates were backward but it was not until I was debugging it, and I didnt want to mess with fixing that.

Answer (score 1):

Standard path finding algorithms should work, you'll need to modify them to match your world definition.

But A* or D* algorithms work pretty well. They use a graph, which you should be able to define from your world definition. (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*)

Also Dijstra's algorithm should work at finding a path (again uses a graph). It is commonly used for network routing - but it also works for normal path finding. (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm)

Basically my approach would be to turn your maze definition into a graph (nodes are "join points", edges are the "hallways") and then use one of those algorithms.